# Is online counselling as effective as face to face?

Tags: cognitive-science

I came across a website for a therapy service offering online counselling and in the text on the website it makes the claim

> "Online counselling is just as effective as face to face"

Has this been shown through any formal evaluations? Their website was focused on couples.

Note I've taken out the specifics of where it came from.

[image]